# insert comma separate value with same id in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with comma separated values when fetch and insert to 1 table from to another table,

my problem is,

I am using PHP, Mysql

**table_1** has comma separated values like this

```
1 | apple1, apple2, apple3 
2 | samsung1,samsung2, samsung3, samsung4
3 | nokia1,nokia2
```

I want to fetch these values from above table and inset to another table with same id, like this
 
**table_2**

 
1 | 1 | apple1
2 | 1 | apple2
3 | 1 | apple3
4 | 2 | samsung1
5 | 2 | samsung2
6 | 2 | samsung3
7 | 2 | samsung4
8 | 3 | nokia1
9 | 3 | nokia2

please anyone can help me to resolve this problem I have a big comma separated table to insert with this,

thanks!

Comment: Hi, I used explode function to insert values, itz worked well only for values, id failed to insert duplicate ID to those

Answer (score 0):

insert, then transform.

```
load infile
```

is what you need for insert

to convert columns to rows, `select id, col1 from table union all id col2 from table union all id, col3 from table...`

Comment: Dear friend Im expecting php mysql answer for this without using load files, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets for example you have this value at once.. apple1,apple2,apple3 and i think a variable will contain them for example it is `$container`
it is a string so make it first an array as

```
$arr=(explode(",", $container));
```

now here is a approach of `foreach` loop in php
and if you are geting id for each $container uniquely then just do it as

```
$id //your id container variable
```

apply your insertion query as:

```
foreach($arr as $val)
{
mysqli_query($con, "insert into table_name set r_id='$id',val='$val'");
}
```

it will insert your comma seperated string for each unique row...

Comment: Yes dr, but how can I insert same ID with same result, as I mentioned above in my second table. using this method I can only insert apple1, apple2, apple3 values, but I failed to insert ID
Thanks for your time

Comment: are you getting id from somewhere ....?  hmmm

Comment: id get from first table, eg : id=1 for apple, id=2 for samsung like,